# Copy build time assets to assets directory of APK CMake

Tags: android, cmake

I have spirv shaders being compiled at build time and I need them to be copied into the APK once it's build with CMake. I tried using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets` but they did not end up in the apk. The only thing that worked is manually copying to build/intermediates which seems hacky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it in gradle build system.

Add following to gradle.kts file.

Running the "buildApk" task will build the shader, copy to assets directory, build apk and check inside apk if shader is in assets directory of generated apk.

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption
import  java.util.zip.ZipFile

// Build your shader and copy it to assets folder.
tasks.register("buildShader") {
    dependsOn("configureCMakeDebug")
    dependsOn("buildCMakeDebug")
    doLast {
        val shaderName = "libhello.so"
        val shader = project.fileTree("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/cxx/Debug/") {
            include("**/$shaderName")
        }.files.firstOrNull()
        // Copying just first one you could everything matching the name.
        if (shader != null) {
            val assetsShader = File("${project.projectDir}/src/main/assets/$shaderName")
            Files.move(shader.toPath(), assetsShader.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
        }
    }
}
// Once shader is copied build apk.
tasks.register("buildApk") {
    dependsOn("buildShader")
    dependsOn("assembleDebug")
    doLast {
        printAssetsDirContents()
    }
}
// Once apk is built, unzip and print contents of apk's assets folder.
fun printAssetsDirContents() {
    val apkFile = File("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk")
    val destinationDir = File("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/debug/unzipped_assets")
    destinationDir.mkdirs()
    ZipFile(apkFile).use { zip ->
        zip.entries().asSequence().forEach { entry ->
            if (entry.name.startsWith("assets/")) {
                zip.getInputStream(entry).use { input ->
                    File(destinationDir, entry.name.substringAfter("assets/")).outputStream().use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println("Files in assets folder:")
    destinationDir.listFiles()?.forEach {
        println(it.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. But is there to like run glslc from here?

Comment: You can run any other build system, just by attaching another task . 
  tasks.register<Exec>("cmakeBuild") {
    workingDir = File("path/to/your/project")
    commandLine("cmake", "--build", "build")
}

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for cmake only answer so here is what I'm doing currently

```
# this is just the path of the root repo since it allows building for windows too
# see the full repo if you want: https://github.com/Denzy7/test-vulkan
set(testvkpath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../..")
add_library(GFX SHARED ...)
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
set(glslc_src
    vert.glsl.vert
    frag.glsl.frag)
foreach(src ${glslc_src})
    set(insrc ${testvkpath}/${src})
    get_filename_component(bare ${src} NAME_WE)
    set(outsrc ${testvkpath}/apk/app/src/main/assets/${bare}.spv)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${outsrc}
        COMMAND ${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE} ${insrc} -o ${outsrc}
        DEPENDS ${insrc} 
        VERBATIM
        )
    list(APPEND spirv ${outsrc})
endforeach()
add_custom_target(shaders 
    DEPENDS ${spirv})
add_dependencies(GFX shaders)
```

`./gradle assembleDebug` has to run twice so build system picks the shaders than ended up `app/src/main/assets`